# Creating .exe thru Iexpress with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, exe, iexpress

I'd like to know if there is any way to get a batch file to generate a .exe file with Iexpress for example. For example with a .sed file launch iexpress to instantly generate the .exe

Answer (score 1):

Very Easy (Type `Iexpress /?` for more info):

```
Iexpress /N Sedfile.sed
```

Add a `/q` after the `/n` to make it work in quit mode.

Mona